# How transport the values of a specific column of a dataframe only to the first match of each combination?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df_1` has the columns `team1` and `team2`, and `df_2` has the columns `runner_home` and `runner_away`.

I would like that when the values of these columns are the same in any of the rows of both dataframes, then the value of the `odds` column in `df_2` is transferred to the `odds` column in `df_1`.

However, if there are multiple rows in `df_1` that match with `df_2`, the odds value should only be defined in the first row, and the others should keep their original value.

Here is an example of the dataframes:

```python
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':['2023-04-25', '2023-04-25', '2024-06-15', '2023-04-25', '2024-10-02'],
    'team1':['Chelsea', 'Barcelona', 'Vasco', 'Barcelona', 'Vasco'],
    'team2':['Liverpool', 'Real Madrid', 'Flamengo', 'Real Madrid', 'Flamengo'],
    'odds':['', '', '', '', '']
})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'runner_home':['Barcelona', 'Vasco'],
    'runner_away':['Real Madrid', 'Flamengo'],
    'odds':[2.50, 1.50]
})
```

And here is how I would like `df_1` dataframe to look like after the modifications:

```python
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':['2023-04-25', '2023-04-25', '2024-06-15', '2023-04-25', '2024-10-02'],
    'team1':['Chelsea', 'Barcelona', 'Vasco', 'Barcelona', 'Vasco'],
    'team2':['Liverpool', 'Real Madrid', 'Flamengo', 'Real Madrid', 'Flamengo'],
    'odds':['', 2.50, 1.50, '', '']
})
```

```
         date      team1        team2 odds
0  2023-04-25    Chelsea    Liverpool     
1  2023-04-25  Barcelona  Real Madrid  2.5
2  2024-06-15      Vasco     Flamengo  1.5
3  2023-04-25  Barcelona  Real Madrid     
4  2024-10-02      Vasco     Flamengo
```

I tried to use `merge`, but I couldn't find a way to make the value stay only in the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a deduplicated merge with help of [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
cols1 = ['team1', 'team2']
cols2 = ['runner_home', 'runner_away']

df_1['odds'] = (df_1
 .drop(columns='odds', errors='ignore')
 .merge(df_2, how='left',
        left_on=cols1+[df_1.groupby(cols1).cumcount()],
        right_on=cols2+[df_2.groupby(cols2).cumcount()])
 ['odds']
)
```

Output:

```
         date      team1        team2  odds
0  2023-04-25    Chelsea    Liverpool   NaN
1  2023-04-25  Barcelona  Real Madrid   2.5
2  2024-06-15      Vasco     Flamengo   1.5
3  2023-04-25  Barcelona  Real Madrid   NaN
4  2024-10-02      Vasco     Flamengo   NaN
```